# Setting opacity of certain divs to .7 when other particular divs are selected

Tags: jquery, css

So I have a list of divs that appear in a vertical order. Two of which contain links that appear when they are clicks (.expand). What I am trying to do is when you click on either of the .expand divs, the rest of the divs will fade to .7 opacity, including the other .expand. I am relatively new to jquery, so making if else syntax is not my strongest skill... That is what I presume will make this request work. Though I am open to any solution.

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'none')
        e.style.display = 'block';
   else
        e.style.display = 'none';
    }

    <div>
        <a href="/"target="_blank" class="business">div1</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="/"target="_blank" class="invention">div2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="expand"> 
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('1expandhiddenlinks');"class="business" ><span class="plus">+</span> expand1</a>
        <div id="1expandhiddenlinks" style="display:none">
                <a href="/"target="_blank" class="business" style="color:#f36523">1</a><br />
                <a href="/"target="_blank" class="business" style="color:#f36523">2</a><br />
                <a href="/"target="_blank" class="business" style="color:#f36523">3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="/"target="_blank" class="invention">div4</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="/"target="_blank" class="invention">div5</a>
    </div>      
    <div>
        <a href="/" target="_blank" class="brand">div6</a><br />
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="/" target="_blank" class="brand">div7</a><br />
    </div>
    <div class="expand">
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('2expandhiddenlinks');" class="brand"><span class="plus">+</span>  expand2</a><br />
            <div id="2expandhiddenlinks" style="display:none">
                <a href="/"target="_blank" class="business" style="color:#f36523">Keep It or Pass It</a><br />
                <a href="/"target="_blank" class="business" style="color:#f36523">Shake (shops)</a><br />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="/" target="_blank" class="brand">div8</a><br/>
    </div>
```

Comment: 1.  your HTML has duplicate IDs - this is bad!  2. you need to show your `toggle_visibility` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this? : http://jsfiddle.net/8quaH/1/

**Edit**
I added a fade effect:

```
$(function(){
    $("#container").find("div").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("expand"))
            $(this).fadeTo(300, 1).siblings().fadeTo(300, .4);
        else
            $("#container").find("div").fadeTo(300, 1);
    }); 
});
```

See [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) doc.

Comment: Yes. This is what I am trying to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: Though is doesn't seem to be fading the a href in each div. thoughts?

Comment: @JeanHules Do you want to hide the expand 1 when you click on the expan 2, like this? : http://jsfiddle.net/8quaH/8/

Comment: I like that. is it possible to make the opacity go back to 1 when both expand 1 and expand 2 go back to closed state?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to to declare CSS class name that has the opacity you want, then add or remove this class from the items in question.

```
$('.expand').addClass('faded')
```

Comment: will jQuery handle correct interpolation to a specified class?

Comment: except that he did say "fade", implying a _gradual_ change in opacity.

Comment: CSS3 supports gradual fading.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$('div.expand').click(function(){
    $('div').not(this).animate({'opacity':.7})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does what you're asking:

```
$('#menu .expand > a').on('click', function() {

    var $sibs = $(this).siblings('div').toggle();
    var vis = $sibs.filter(':visible').length > 0; // check visibility
    var opacity = vis ? 0.2 : 1.0;                 // required opacity

    $(this).parent().css('opacity', 1).siblings().animate({
        'opacity': opacity
    });
});
```

I added a wrapper `div` around the whole lot to isolate the effects to the menu.

Note that this also:

1. completely removes the need for inline event handlers
2. also handles toggling the display of the sub elements

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/LBhgZ/

I don't make any claims for its efficiency - there are probably better ways to check whether the toggle showed or hid the submenu.

Comment: Use :first-child, instead of :first

Comment: So once the .expand is expanded, so to speak, on the click that toggles the div to close back up, how can I make the opacity go back to 1?

Comment: @JeanHules it already does - in the code above the clicked section always gets its opacity set to 1, whether it's opening or closing.

Comment: @JeanHules or did you mean on every _other_ section?  You never said what you wanted to happen to those.

Comment: @Alnitak Sorry for being unclear. Ya, I was hoping the opacity of the rest would go back to 1 if either expands were toggled to closes state

Comment: @JeanHules ok, I think this does it now.